# Validacion de error test laravel por la key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo las 2 siguientes cuestiones

1. Al realizar los test en Laravel, la forma de validar los mensajes de error eran:

   ->assertSessionHasErrors(['last_name' => '¿Cuál es tu apellido?']);

pero el problema de esto es que si es una aplicación multi-lenguaje tengo que generar esos mensajes para todo y lo que quiero hacer es validar por la key del error, como por ejemplo:

```
 $this->assertJsonError($response, 'user.name.required')  
 $this->assertJsonError($response, 'user.email.unique')
```

Hay algún método para  verificar esto o habría que generarlo uno?

2. El segundo es que es una apliación tanto web como mobile, entonces la duda es,

> todos los endpoints irian en la rutas api, salvo las del login web?
>   para no estar duplicando rutas

y al hacer esto, al querer ingresar desde un navegador web, se puede quitar el /api/v1/... ? pero si mantenerlos para la parte mobile?

Comment: Hola, son dos preguntas completamente diferentes, sería mejor que abrieras una nueva pregunta con la segunda cuestión. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a tu primera pregunta, para traerte mensajes en los diferentes lenguajes a la hora de hacer las *asserts*, usa la función `trans()` de Laravel, por ejemplo:

```
$this->assertJsonError($response, trans('user.email.unique'));
```